# what is the problem of this if statement block?

Tags: c++, sorting

I have written this console-app as an exercise, but bumped into a problem with one of the if statements. I can't understand where the problem is, could somebody help me with this?

It wouldn't arrange alphabetically the bold section I mean `s3`, `s1`, `s2`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string s1, s2, s3;
    cout << "Please enter three words: ";
    cin >> s1;
    cin >> s2;
    cin >> s3;

    if(s1.compare(s2)<0)
    {
        if(s2.compare(s3)<0)
        {
            cout << s1 << ", " << s2 << ", " << s3 << endl;
        }
        else 
            cout << s1 << ", " << s3 << ", " << s2 << endl;
    }
    else if (s2.compare(s3)<0)
    {
        if(s1.compare(s3)<0)
        {
            cout << s2 << ", " << s1 << ", " << s3 << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << s2 << ", " << s3 << ", " << s1 << endl;
    }
    else if(s3.compare(s2)<0)
    {
        if(s1.compare(s2)<0) // <-- HERE!!
        {
            cout << s3 << ", " << s1 << ", " << s2 << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << s3 << ", " << s2 << ", " << s1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? can you mention it

Comment: You need to learn about arrays (e.g. `std::vector`) and how to loop over the contents. There's excessive amounts of duplicated code here which could be reduced to a more minimal form with a simple loop. You can also use tools like [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to sort for you in an instant.

Comment: You also need to learn how to step through your code with a debugger, so you can see exactly what each statement actually does at runtime, and you can see where your code deviates from what you are expecting. Using a debugger is a vital skill for a programmer.

Comment: `std::strings` are groovy. They have a `<` operator.

Comment: @tadman, and thanks for your quick reply, I know I should learn more to do this more efficiently and in less coding but could you just tell me what is the problem and what should I do to output this correctly (cout<<s3<<", "<<s1<<", "<<s2<<endl;)

Comment: What input exactly did you provide to your program? What output did your program produce for the input you provided? What output do you want from your  program? Please update your question with the steps needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: **Use arrays**. You have 6 possible arrangements here for 3 entries, but for 5 entries you'd have 120. This does not scale, and arguably you're not really solving problems here. You're brute-forcing something that does not require brute force.

Comment: Another thing: Use `argv`. Don't ask for input like that. Just take in the command-line arguments, so `myprogram a b c` would have three words supplied automatically.

Comment: apple, banana, kiwi are the input and I input it like this banana, kiwi, apple. the output is banana apple kiwi.

Comment: Looks like you should use a debugger and trace the program execution step by step, to see which path it goes to output 'banana apple kiwi'. Then think about what test was missing on that path, which would allow the program to put 'apple' before 'banana'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some error checking with your code and found out something interesting.

When the order should be S3, S1, S2 the first if statement is still true. You can fix this by using an and statement such as the following:

```
if ((s1.compare(s2) < 0) && (s1.compare(s3) < 0)) 
{ 
... code here ...
}
```

This additional code in your if statements will keep errors from happening.
I hope this helps!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string s1, s2, s3;
    cout<<"Please enter three words: ";
    cin>>s1;
    cin>>s2;
    cin>>s3;
    if((s1.compare(s2)<0) && (s1.compare(s3)<0))
    {
        if(s2.compare(s3)<0)
        {
            cout<<s1<<", "<<s2<<", "<<s3<<endl;
        }
        else 
        cout<<s1<<", "<<s3<<", "<<s2<<endl;
    }
    else if ((s2.compare(s3)<0) && (s2.compare(s1)<0))
    {
        if(s1.compare(s3)<0)
        {
            cout<<s2<<", "<<s1<<", "<<s3<<endl;
        }
        else
        cout<<s2<<", "<<s3<<", "<<s1<<endl;
    }

    else if((s3.compare(s2)<0) && (s3.compare(s1)<0))
    {
        if(s1.compare(s2)<0)
        {
            cout<<s3<<", "<<s1<<", "<<s2<<endl;
        }
        else
        cout<<s3<<", "<<s2<<", "<<s1<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually suggesting a way to make it better.  It would be great if you could show a complete sample for checking all the cases.

Comment: Yeah! I guess that would be helpful. Sorry I'm still new to this haha.

Comment: This code does more work than necessary – for input like C B A it would perform 7 comparisons to produce an output of A B C, while 3 suffice. Additionally, it doesn't properly handle equal values – for M M M it wouldn't print anything...

Answer (score 0):

Your very first if condition is:

```
if(s1.compare(s2)<0)
```

This means it cannot get to the if statement labelled 'HERE', because it will have always taken the first branch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is much earlier than 'HERE'.

This part

```
if(s1.compare(s2)<0)
{
    if(s2.compare(s3)<0)
    {
        cout << s1 << ", " << s2 << ", " << s3 << endl;
    }
    else 
        cout << s1 << ", " << s3 << ", " << s2 << endl;
}
```

first tests that `s1` is 'less than' `s2`. So you have a partial order `s1`, `s2`.

But then you need to find out in which of **three** possible places the `s3` should go: in front of `s1`, past the `s2`, of possibly between them. However, the internal conditional allows only **two** different outputs...

**Added:**

You can solve the problem starting from the comment above: comparing two elements is enough to sort them. Then you need to compare the third one to both of those to decide if it should go first, second or last:

```
if(s1.compare(s2) <= 0)       // s1 goes before s2
{
    if(s3.compare(s1) <= 0)       // s3 goes before s1
        cout << s3 << ", " << s1 << ", " << s2 << endl;
    else if(s3.compare(s2) <= 0)  // s3 goes before s2 but after s1
        cout << s1 << ", " << s3 << ", " << s2 << endl;
    else                          // s3 goes after s2
        cout << s1 << ", " << s2 << ", " << s3 << endl;
}
else                          // s2 goes before s1
{
    if(s3.compare(s2) <= 0)       // s3 goes before s2
        cout << s3 << ", " << s2 << ", " << s1 << endl;
    else if(s3.compare(s1) <= 0)  // s3 goes before s1 but after s2
        cout << s2 << ", " << s3 << ", " << s1 << endl;
    else                          // s3 goes after s1
        cout << s2 << ", " << s1 << ", " << s3 << endl;
}
```

There are 6 permutations possible for 3 input values, and all of them are available. At each path there are at most 3 comparisions done, which is enough to distinguish each of 6 possible outputs.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the first one should be consistently referenced or patterned by else

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string s1, s2, s3;
    cout << "Please enter three words: ";
    cin >> s1 >> s2 >> s3;

    if(s1.compare(s2)<0)
    {
        if(s2.compare(s3)<0)                                    // repeat this pattern
            cout << s1 << ", " << s2 << ", " << s3 << endl;     //

        else if(s2.compare(s3) == 0)                            //
            cout << s1 << ", " << s2 << " = " << s3 << endl;    //

        else
            cout << s1 << ", " << s3 << ", " << s2 << endl;     //
    }                                                           //
    else if (s2.compare(s3)<0)
    {
        if(s3.compare(s1)<0)
            cout << s2 << ", " << s3 << ", " << s1 << endl;

        else if(s1.compare(s3) == 0)
            cout << s2 << ", " << s1 << " = " << s3 << endl;
        else
            cout << s2 << ", " << s1 << ", " << s3 << endl;
    }
    else if(s1.compare(s3)<0)
    {
        if(s3.compare(s2)<0) // <-- HERE!!

            cout << s1 << ", " << s3 << ", " << s2 << endl;

        else if(s2.compare(s3) == 0)
            cout << s1 << ", " << s2 << " = " << s3 << endl;
        else
            cout << s1 << ", " << s2 << ", " << s3 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```